# How to ignore the return value of an Async function in an Async block?

Tags: f#

The `m1` and `m2` in the following functions have compiling errors.

```
let m p = async { return p * 2 }
let m1 () = async { do! m 2 } // ERR: was expected 'int' but here has type 'unit'
let m2 () = async { do! m 2 |> ignore } // ERR: expecting 'Async<int>->Async<'a>' but given 'Async<int>->unit'
```

`m` is called at the last line. How to ignore its return value? Is the following the only way (will executing of it be optimized by the compiler?)?

```
let m1 () = 
    async { 
      let! x = m 2 
      () 
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? It smells C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Async.Ignore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.ignore%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D) for this:

```
let m1 () = async { do! m 2 |> Async.Ignore }
```

From the documentation:

> [`Async.Ignore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.ignore%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D) Creates an asynchronous computation that runs the given computation and ignores its result.

Comment: btw, it is literally the same as `let m1 () = m 2 |> Async.Ignore`

Comment: The signature of `m1` (the return type) are different?