# The block following this 'let' is unfinished, F# error despite returning the value from function

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, let

```
 | Log (message, ack) ->

         let CreateEventSourcingConnection() =
             task {
                 let connection =
                     let ipEndPoint = IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1113)
                     EventStoreConnection.Create(ipEndlPoint)
                 do! connection.ConnectAsync()
                 return connection
             }

         let AddEventToStreamAsync (connection: IEventStoreConnection) streamName eventName message =
             task {
                 let serializedEventData =
                     message
                     |> JsonConvert.SerializeObject
                     |> Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
                 let event = EventData(Guid.NewGuid(), eventName, true, serializedEventData, null)

                 let! _ = connection.AppendToStreamAsync(streamName, int64 ExpectedVersion.Any, event)
                 ()
             }
```

Error:

```
The block following this 'let' is unfinished. Every code block is an expression and must have a result. 'let' cannot be the final code element in a block. Consider giving this block an explicit result.
```

I have tried calling these functions after defining them. I have also checked my indentation, I think it should be okay. I understand I need to return the value from the function, but I think I already do that.

Comment: At the end of AddEventToStreamAsync - can you try "return ()" instead of "()" ?

Comment: Which `let` statement is causing the error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762436/how-to-ignore-the-return-value-of-an-async-function-in-an-async-block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect (without knowing which `let` statement is causing the error) that you need to be returning something from the pattern match (i.e. the part that comes after `| Log (message, ack) ->`).

If you don't need to return anything, you can just return `()` at the end, at the same level of indentation as the two outer `let`s, but note that all branches of the pattern matching need to return the same type.